# How to move a file on the server to another directory using plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to move a file on the server from one directory to another using plpgsql.

I take some data out of an XML file from the server, write it to tables (this part is working) and after that I want to move the processed file to another location.

In oracle database I used:

```
utl_file.frename(from_dir, file_name, to_dir, file_name);
```

Any ideas if there is some similar function in plpgsql to move file from one location to another?

Also, currently using lo_import and lo_export that need superuser privileges. Is there any other way to do it wihtout superuser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy file from one location to another:

```
create or replace function copy_file(from_path text, to_path text) 
    RETURNS void AS $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
begin
  select lo_import(from_path) into l_oid;
  perform lo_export(l_oid, to_path);
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```